# How to code a "numbers pad" like Call application

Tags: iphone, numpad

how can I do something like this in an iPhone app?

[image: iphone app screenshot]

I need to input a number but I want something like this, not a simple UITextField.

How?

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific - where is this number going? If you don't want a UITextField, what is going to show user feedback for the numbers typed in? It would also help if you let us know what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved with new feature

```
UITextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a custom UIView if you want it to look like what you sent. Basically add a set of subviews (UIButtons) for each control. Then create a delegate for the custom UIView that will notify of value changes. For example, here is some rough code to get you started:

```
// CustomNumbersView.m

- (void)button1DidClick:(id)sender
{
  [self.delegate customNumbersView:self didSelectKeyWithValue:@"1"];
}

- (void)button2DidClick:(id)sender
{
  [self.delegate customNumbersView:self didSelectKeyWithValue:@"2"];
}

// MainViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  CustomNumbersView *customNubmersView = [[CustomNumbersView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
  customNumbersView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)customNumbersView:(CustomNumbersView *)customNumbersView didSelectKeyWithValue:(NSString *)value
{
  self.mainTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.mainTextField.text, value];
}
```

Comment: Yes, for something like that I add a set of subviews. But, for example, when I click "5" button, how can I set in real-time the output on the textfield?

Comment: Hey Joaquin. You need to use the **delegate pattern** to notify your view controller of any button presses. I've put in some code above to get you started and give you a general idea of how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I Agree with Kevin. But if you decide to implement your own keyboard-like pad you may have to lose all those nice features provided by the original iOS keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As I need one in several situations in my programs, I wrote a [delegate-driven KeyPad](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/KeyPad).